# Differentiate Amazon Linux 2 and Amazon Linux AMI 2018.03.0 in Ansible Script

Tags: amazon-ec2, ansible, amazon-ami, ansible-facts

In ansible script, I want to differentiate between **Amazon Linux 2** and **Amazon Linux AMI 2018.03.0** using conditions. Like we use **ansible_os_family** condition, is there any condition function in ansible that I can use to differentiate these two.

My Objective is to run different commands(using ansible script) based on the difference of os (**especially between Amazon Linux 2 and Amazon Linux 2018.03.0**).

Comment: Hi ram n, welcome to SO. Can you [edit your post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61875690/edit) to include what's in the `/etc/os-release` file for each distribution, and/or the output of running `/usr/bin/lsb_release`? It would also be helpful if you would post what you have already tried that is not working for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ansible_distribution_major_version` fact is set to `"2"` and `"2018"` respectively for Amazon Linux 2 vs 2018.03.0 so you can use that for your conditionals like the following:

`when: ansible_distribution_major_version == "2018"`

Answer (score 0):

you can use following ansible fact for this,

```
{{ hostvars[inventory_hostname].ansible_distribution }}
```

And for running different tasks based on condition, do like this

```
- name: <Task name goes here>
  import_tasks: yourtask.yml
  when: hostvars[inventory_hostname].ansible_distribution | lower == 'amazon linux 2'
```